# ES-8.2 - Partial update in a rolled-over index

Tags: elasticsearch

We're using datetime based index with an alias that is rolled over to a new index daily. We managed to achieve this by creating an ingest pipeline that figures out the physical index behind an alias and updates(read replaces) the original document. Now, requirement is to partially update a document in a rolled-over index, meaning, we might get an additional field to update in a document that resides in an index that has been marked as write=false.
If the document is in current write index, update works fine.

But the same update API throws an "Index missing exception" OR "version_conflict_engine_exception" otherwise.

My question is-
Is it possible to achieve this if we don't want to index a fully formed document all the time.

I understand we can achieve this using painless script but I want to avoid runtime processing for performance boost.

This is my pipeline

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/transaction_index_pipeline
{
  "description": "Adds ingest time to document + figures out the destination index if it's a dated transaction",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "_source.ingest_time",
        "value": "{{{_ingest.timestamp}}}"
      }
    },
    {
    "script": {
      "description": "Set index based on `payload_ts` field",
       "lang": "painless",
      "source": """
        long today = new Date().getTime();
        long payloadTs = ctx['payload_ts'] ;
        
        LocalDate payloadDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(payloadTs).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        LocalDate currentDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(today).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

        if(payloadDate.isBefore(currentDate)){
        //if(payloadTs < today){
          ctx['_index'] = ctx['_index'] + '-' + payloadDate +'-' + '000001';  
        }
      """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Existing document

```
{
        "_index": "transactions-2022-07-03-000001",
        "_id": "1000",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "ingest_time": "2022-07-05T09:51:20.669234421Z",
          "reg": "UNR",
          "payload_ts": 1656806400000,
          "fully": "formed1"
        }
      }
```

update request

```
POST /transactions/_update/1000 
{
  "doc" : {
    "newfield" : 10000 ,
    "payload_ts":1656806400000
  } 
}
```

exception

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
        "reason": "[1000]: version conflict, required seqNo [143], primary term [1]. current document has seqNo [55] and primary term [1]",
        "index_uuid": "l6gM62jwQSq92zhU1im1-w",
        "shard": "0",
        "index": "transactions-2022-07-03-000001"
      }
    ],
    "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
    "reason": "[1000]: version conflict, required seqNo [143], primary term [1]. current document has seqNo [55] and primary term [1]",
    "index_uuid": "l6gM62jwQSq92zhU1im1-w",
    "shard": "0",
    "index": "transactions-2022-07-03-000001"
  },
  "status": 409
}
```

Comment: Update a document in es, wathever if you only target a field or the whole document will reindex the whole document (with nested documents if any). So as if you have "'partial update" tool on clients side, partial update doesnot exist on serveur (es) side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not sure if that's entirely true, partial updates are possible in ES. If I don't use pipeline, update works just fine.

Comment: hmm, maybe it s change, but, as i remember, the only difference is es doesnot have to retrieve document first, but all fields are reindex in both case: https://techieroop.com/partial-update-in-elasticsearch/

Comment: I will try to get more inforamtion about es 7-8 about it, please share if you have some documents on your side.